# How to remove this featured in xenforo?

Tags: xenforo

Please help me how to remove the unread thread features in xenforo

[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9faSz.jpg)

Comment: You want to change phrase or whole section?

Answer (score 0):

That phrase is named no_unread_posts_view_latest

It appears in this widget: widget_new_posts

and this template: whats_new_posts

Disable the widget or remove the div which contains the phrase.